# Hamming window generates a line

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, hamming-window

I have an audio file and read all data from the sound card buffer. Then, I convert `byte[]` to `float[]` to use them for hamming window. The waveform of the audio is:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NhTB.png]

after using hamming window:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N87qE.png]

is the waveform of audio with hamming window right? Where is my mistake?

by the way i use naudio library to process audio:

```
WaveChannel32 wave = new WaveChannel32(new WaveFileReader("sesDosyası.wav"));
byte []buffer = new byte[wave.length];
float []data = new float[wave.length / 4];
int read = wave.Read(buffer, 0, wave.length);
for (int i = 0; i < read / 4; i++)
{   
    data[i] = BitConverter.ToSingle(buffer, i * 4); //converting byte to float
    chart1.Series["wave"].Points.Add(data[i]); //first waveform
}

for (int j = 0; j < read/4; j++)
{
   data[j] = (float)(0.54 - 0.46 * Math.Cos((2 * Math.PI * data[j]) / (read / 4 - 1)));//hamming
   chart2.Series["wave"].Points.Add(data[j]); //second waveform
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are applying the window to the whole wave, so `read` is going to be huge, so the term inside the `cos` is always going to be very near 0 for a `data` between [-1,1].

So you are always getting `.54 - .46*cos(0)` = `.54 - .46*1.0` = `.08`

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Hann_.28Hanning.29_window), only `j` should be inside the cosine - that gives the window, which you then multiply by `data[j]`:

```
window =  0.54 - 0.46 * Math.Cos( (2*Math.PI * j)/(total - 1) ).
hammed_signal = data[j]*window;
```

Why are you trying to apply a hamming window to the whole wave?

Comment: how much should be size of my blocks? i mean if read data by 4096 byte array blocks, will it be solved?

Comment: If you replace `data[j]` with `j`, you will get the right window.  The right block size depends on what you want to do.

Comment: i read audio data by 16 byte array and convert float arrays. i use hamming for each data block and it generates: http://c1303.hizliresim.com/17/1/kmnc7.png

Comment: ok ok nevermind i understand now.. i must use your code. thank u so much! i have a last question. when i use "n" bytes array block to read the data the waveform with hamming is like that; n=16 => http://d1303.hizliresim.com/17/1/kmnzq.png n=4096 =>http://d1303.hizliresim.com/17/1/kmp0z.png and n=16384 => http://d1303.hizliresim.com/17/1/kmp1s.png how much should be size of my blocks?

Comment: No one can tell you what block size to use unless you tell us why you are hamming?  What audio effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to extract feature of an audio by using these steps which some of them makes wave of the audio better to analysis: 1-frame blocking 2-windowing 3-fft 4-Mel-Frequency Warping 5-Cepstrum

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5570485/10396 for a good explanation of window sizes for FFT.  Basically you need to balance the frequency resolution you need after the FFT with the time resolution needed after you convert back.  If you FFT the whole wave, you get super-detailed frequency resolution, but you get one big smear of sound when you convert back to a wave.

Comment: actually i will fft to area of speech in the wave not whole wave. thanks for all your helping

Answer (score 1):

I think your hamming line is wrong:

```
data[j] = (float)(0.54 - 0.46 * Math.Cos((2 * Math.PI * data[j]) / (read - 1)));
```

As your loop goes from `0` to `read/4`, and you are dividing by `read`, so if you have read 16 samples, your for loop looks only at the first 4, but divides by 15, not 3.

```
var total = read / 4;

for (int j = 0; j < total; j++)
{
   data[j] = (float)(0.54 - 0.46 * Math.Cos((2 * Math.PI * data[j]) / (total- 1)));//hamming
   chart2.Series["wave"].Points.Add(data[j]); //second waveform
}
```